# How to make commit fail if pre-commit linting fails

Tags: angular, git, eslint, pre-commit, husky

I'm using Husky `7.0.0` to create a pre-commit hook to run linting checks in an Angular `12.2.13` app using eslint `7.26.0`. I want to make the commit fail if there are linting issues, i.e. a missing import.

My current setup (which is not working and lets the user commit code with missing imports):

`package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
...
"prepare": "husky install",
"lint-staged": "lint-staged",
"stylelint-staged": "stylelint --syntax scss"
}
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "ng lint --staged && ng test",
    "pre-push": "ng build --prod true"
  }
},
"lint-staged": {
   "src/app/**/**/*.{ts,html}": "eslint",
   "src/app/**/**/*.scss": "stylelint"
},
"pre-commit": "lint-staged",
...
```

`.husky/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

echo "running pre commit hook"
npm test
lint-staged --relative
npm run pre-commit-checks
```

Please let me know where I'm wrong. Thank your for your help!

Comment: Have you installed husky hooks? Newer versions of husky doesn't install hooks automatically.

Comment: That's curious, since "prevent commit if pre-commit hook says prevent commit" is kind of the point of a pre-commit hook. :-) The usual first diagnostic would be to modify the existing pre-commit hook to print out a loud message "I AM RUNNING NOW" (and maybe pause for a moment so you can see it, if the things the pre-commit hook does cause output to be obscured).

Comment: @torek how can I write to console? I've updated my setup above, and when committing, I don't get the output of `echo` anywhere.

Comment: The output already *does* go to the window/console/whatever in which the command line is running. If you're not getting the output, that means the script is not running: investigate why. (See Monsieur Merso's note that you must take particular steps to *install* hooks.)

Comment: @MonsieurMerso I've followed the setup recommended by husky, and i couldn't find anything about separately installing husky hooks?

Comment: @gizmo can you show us output of your `git status` and output of `ng lint --staged && ng test` if hooks are configured well I can see 2 reasons for them to not work, if there is nothing to lint (no changes on the project) or linting rules are not configured to catch things that you expect them to catch.

Comment: I've been able to fix it, my mistake was that i needed to have this line in .husky/pre-commit: `npm run pre-commit` and then `lint-staged` in the husky pre-commit hook in the package.json. now the commit fails if there's an error